# jQuery is not defined joomla

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, joomla

> Tenho um código para as animções do meu site joomla utilizando o jQuery, entretanto observei pelo inspector que alguns dias após a atualização de versão do php, essas animações pararam de funcionar e esse erro apareceu. Já tentei retornar a versão antiga mas o erro persiste. Este é um dos trechos do meu código que está com esse problema. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma outra forma para declara esse jQuery.

```
t.fn.spbalert = function (e)
{
    return this.each(function ()
    {
        var n = t(this),
            s = n.data("sppb.alert");
        s || n.data("sppb.alert", s = new i(this)), "string" == typeof e && s[e].call(n)
    })
}, t.fn.spbalert.Constructor = i, t.fn.spbalert.noConflict = function ()
{
    return t.fn.spbalert = n, this
}, t(document).on("click.sppb.alert.data-api", e, i.prototype.close)}(jQuery),
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o $ no lugar do jQuery?

Comment: Ainda não. Vou tentar. Muito obrigada